# Why does my code is executed after window location?

Tags: javascript, php

I wonder why my code is executed after I use

```
window.location
```

and how I can avoid it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!confirm("question?"))
    {
        window.location = 'index.php?a=my_posts';
    }
</script>

<?php
delete("spikes","id",$id);
?>
```

Why does the php code is executed when the condition inside the if statement returns true?

Comment: That PHP code is going to be executed every time you load the page, regardless of the JavaScript code.

Comment: "and how I can avoid it?"

Comment: As a complement to David comment. PHP is a SERVER-SIDE script which means the it will execute before the page get to the client and execute the javascript code that is CLIENT-SIDE script

Comment: By putting in some kind of conditional?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  PHP code executes server-side *before* the page is delivered to the browser.  JavaScript code executes client-side *after* the page is delivered to the browser.  The two are *completely* unrelated.  What are you actually *trying* to do?  Currently you have a single line of PHP code which executes when the page is requested.  If you're trying to do something different than that, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The php code is the code that should be executed in the else block of the if statement but I can't do that since you can't run php functions throguh javascript as far as I know.

Comment: @ImriPersiado: If you want the PHP code to only execute under certain conditions, then that condition needs to be checked in PHP code.  (Note: PHP also has `if` statements you can use.)  Maybe what you want here is to move the PHP code to a separate page and make an AJAX request to that page from the JavaScript code?  That's the simplest option I can think of based on what you've described so far.

Comment: I need to execute the window.location line if the user confirms the question and if he doesn't I need to execute the delete function. I can't use php if staement since the confirm() function is a javascript function.. wait... maybe if(<script type="text/javascript">!confirm("question?")</script>) is possible??

Comment: @ImriPersiado: I doubt that's possible, since that's neither valid PHP nor valid JavaScript.  If the condition is being checked client-side, then the client-side code would need to then make a request to server-side code in response to the conditional.  That's where AJAX comes in.  There are *tons* of tutorials online for how to make an AJAX request to a second PHP page (which would contain the PHP code you want to execute in response to the conditional).  Using a library like jQuery makes it pretty trivial, just using the `$.get()` function with the URL of the page.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer with some lines of code?sounds like an answer to me. Thanks.

Comment: If you do it like this you are setting yourself up for a wonderful way of unauthorized requests. Anyone can deletey anything they want.